# Characterizing worldly cardinals as the supremum (by n) of least $\Sigma_n$-extendible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

A cardinal $\kappa$ is called $\Sigma_n$-extendible iff there is some $\theta$ such that $V_\kappa\prec_{n} V_\theta$. That is, they agree on the truth of $\Sigma_n$ assertions with parameters from $V_\kappa$. A cardinal $\kappa$ is called worldly iff $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC. Question:

> Consider $\sup_n(\min\{\alpha\mid \alpha \text{ is } \Sigma_n\text{-extendible}\})$.
> Is this cardinal the least worldly cardinal?

An observation: if we let $\kappa$ be the least worldly cardinal, then since $\Sigma_n$-satisfaction for $V_\kappa$ is definable, by the reflection principle we are able to find $V_\alpha\prec_n V_\kappa$ for each $n$ in $V_\kappa$. So $\sup_n(\min\{\alpha\mid \alpha \text{ is } \Sigma_n\text{-extendible}\})$ is not greater than the least worldly cardinal. Is it possible that it is smaller?

Comment: I think that you can prove the existence of these so-called $\Sigma_n$-extendible cardinals from ZFC, because there is a closed and unbounded class of $\Sigma_n$-correct ordinals, and I suspect that you will find many of them being $\Sigma_n$-extendible as well.

Comment: Your question motivated me a following new (and possibly relevant) question: is a limit $\delta$ of cardinals $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ satisfies $\Sigma_n$-replacement also satisfies $V_\delta\models\text{$\Sigma_n$-replacement}$? This is true for $n=1$, and your problem has an affirmative answer if it holds.

Comment: @HanulJeon that's a nice question, maybe you can post that question and have this one linked as well? Also, Joel Hamkins's comment under this answer might be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161250/questions-about-worldly-cardinals/161254#161254

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree that for each $n$, ZFC might be able to prove the existence of $\Sigma_n$-extendible cardinals. It's unclear whether ZFC can prove "for all $n$, $\Sigma_n$-extendible cardinals exist". It certainly cannot, if the sup of these minimum $\Sigma_n$-extendibles turns out to be worldly

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/135995/7206 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/225659/7206 seem like relevant starting points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. I claim that the supremum can see the
$\omega$-cofinal sequence $\kappa_n$, where $\kappa_n$ is the least
$\Sigma_n$-extendible cardinal.

The main point is that if $\alpha$ is $\Sigma_{n+1}$-extendible, so
$V_\alpha\prec_{\Sigma_{n+1}}V_\beta$ for some $\beta$, then
$V_\beta$ can see that $\alpha$ is $\Sigma_n$-extendible, and so
the least $\Sigma_n$-extendible is in fact less than $\alpha$. So
each next $\Sigma_{n+1}$-extendible cardinal must be beyond the $\beta$ used for
the $\Sigma_n$-extendibility of the least $\Sigma_n$-extendible cardinal. Therefore, the limit $\kappa$ of the
least $\Sigma_n$-extendibles can see that they are like that, so by restricting the definition of $\prec_{\Sigma_{n+1}}$ just to $V_\beta$
it can define the cofinal $\omega$-sequence, which means it
isn't even $\Sigma_2$-extendible.

Another argument: if $\kappa$ is the least worldly cardinal, then let $\delta<\kappa$ be $\Sigma_2$-correct in $V_\kappa$, which is possible, because ZFC proves that the $\Sigma_2$-correct cardinals form a club. But $V_\delta$ is correct about whether a cardinal is $\Sigma_n$-extendible, and whether there is one. So the whole sequence is below $\delta$.

Comment: I think your main can be strengthened: namely, if $\alpha$ is $\Sigma_{n+1}$-extendible, then $V_\alpha$ thinks the class of all $\Sigma_n$-extendible cardinals is unbounded.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this follows easily, since if $\alpha$ has the property in $V_\beta$, then it must be unbounded.